# How to show members with block = 1 first only if p.user is the page creator?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have a page and this page has a owner.

I'd like to select members of this page.

The problem is, **if** it is the page owner who is logged in (how created the page) I'd like to **show first** (**and only for him**) the members with block = 1 for join autorization.

So I have:

```
CREATE TABLE `page` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, // who created the page.
  `title` varchar(40),
  `privado` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
)
```

and page_members (who join the page):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `page_members` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, // who is joining
  `member` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, // page id
  `block` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', // block 1 = need autorization
  FOREIGN KEY (`member`) REFERENCES page (`id`)
)
```

Suppose I have a page that user 1 created, and it has members.
I'd like to select **first** the members with **block = 1 if who is logged in is the page owner** (page table, user). if it is not the page owner, I'd like to select only members with block = 0.

So I tried:

```
select p.user, p.title, pm.user, pm.block from page_members pm
left join page p on pm.member = p.id
where pm.member = 100 // show members from page 100
```

.

```
    and p.user = 1 // from here I'm not sure what to do, 
I'd like to select and show first the members with block = 1 
but only if p.user = 1 (the page owner).
```

If p.user = 2, for example, he is not the page owner, so don't show members with block 1, only block 0.

any ideas?

Comment: What does "First member" mean. How do you sort this for "First"?

Comment: @JNevill first THE members. sorry. I'll edit.

Comment: OH! gotcha. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: When it's the page owner, do you want to select *both* block = 1 and block = 0, or just block = 1?

Comment: @Barmar for page owner it is both! who is not the owner only block = 0

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IF()` around a condition to make it dependent on some other condition.

```
select p.user, p.title, pm.user, pm.block 
from page_members pm
left join page p on pm.member = p.id AND IF(p.user = @logged_in_user, true, pm.block = 0)
where pm.member = 100
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. can I also use `order by pm.block desc` to show users with block = 1 first? is it ok?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the results after the join:

```
select p.user, p.title, pm.user, pm.block from page_members pm
left join page p on pm.member = p.id
where pm.member = 100 
and ((p.user = 1) or ((p.user !=1) and (pm.block = 0)))
order by p.user, pm.block desc
```

and with the order by you have the sort you want

Comment: Tests of `p` columns should be in the `ON` clause because it's a `LEFT JOIN`.